# How do I prevent an eclipse/jface/swt application from flickering

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a problem using swt, jface and eclipse controls in a bigger application. When opening and closing a new shell (some popup menu) combined with `requestLayout()` in the main application some controls "flicker".

I already did a lot of debugging and got to the following conclusion:

- The problem appears when using specific controls inside a `org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder`/`org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem`
- Default SWT Controls (e.g. `Combo`/`Text`) don't flicker
- Using a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link` widget (also happens for e.g. a `org.eclipse.riena.ui.swt.CompletionCombo`) inside the tab will result in flickering
- To simply reproduce the problem I open and close a second shell (basically what we do in our application with a pop up) and call `requestLayout()` on an element in the `CTabFolder`
- The problem dose not show on controls outside of the `CTabFolder`

I created a small implementation to reproduce/show the problem:
[display flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK8Tv.gif)

While the `CompletionCombo` is partly a riena implementation, the `Link` is stock eclipse. So here is the code using only the `Link`:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTTestCaseFlickering {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SWTTestCaseFlickering window = new SWTTestCaseFlickering();
        window.open();
    }



    public void open() {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).applyTo(shell);

        CTabFolder f = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(f);
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).span(1, 21).hint(100, 100).applyTo(f);
        CTabItem i = new CTabItem(f, SWT.NONE);
        i.setText("YOYOYOO");

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            Link l = new Link(shell, SWT.NONE);
            l.setText("link!!");
        }

        Composite mainComp = new Composite(f, SWT.NONE);
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(mainComp);
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).applyTo(mainComp);

        i.setControl(mainComp);

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            Link l = new Link(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
            l.setText("link!!");
            Combo c = new Combo(mainComp, SWT.BORDER);
            c.setItems("a", "b", "c");
            c.select(0);
        }

        Link l = new Link(mainComp, SWT.NONE);
        l.setText("link!!");
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).span(3, 1).applyTo(l);

        Button b = new Button(mainComp, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("open-close-shell-requestLayout");
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).span(3, 1).applyTo(b);
        b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent pE) {
                Shell s = new Shell(shell);
                org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(s);
                s.pack();
                s.open();
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> {
                    s.close();
                    b.requestLayout();
                });
            }
        });
        Button b2 = new Button(mainComp, SWT.PUSH);
        b2.setText("open-dispose-shell-requestLayout");
        org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).span(3, 1).applyTo(b2);
        b2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent pE) {
                Shell s = new Shell(shell);
                org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(s);
                s.pack();
                s.open();
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> {
                    s.dispose();
                    b2.requestLayout();
                });
            }
        });
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some of the environment infos:

- Java Version: `openjdk version "1.8.0_252" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)`
- SWT: org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.114.0.v20200304-0601.jar
- JFace: org.eclipse.jface_3.19.0.v20200218-1607.jar

Comment: I can't reproduce this on macOS. Maybe try a newer SWT/JFace - but beware that the latest SWT now requires Java 11.

Comment: Note: `GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(f)` setting a layout on CTabFolder doesn't do anything, CTabFolder has its own layout and ignores anything you set.

Comment: will do - thx for testing @greg-449

Comment: We tested some more: Linux was working fine - no flickering.  JFace 3.23/SWT 3.117 on windows -> problem was reproducible. So it looks like a "Windows-only" problem.